# Add reference to a .NET Core 2.0 DLL on a Full Framework 4.7 project

Tags: .net, .net-core

I looked for this question in here but I didn't find the answer.

I have a Class Library project targeting .NET Core 2.0 and a WPF project targeting .NET Full Framework 4.7. I can't reference the class library on the WPF project. I get the following error:

> Project 'xxxxxxxx' targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. It cannot be
>   referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7'.

Is there any way to reference a .NET Core project in a Full Framework one?

Comment: May be this helps https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You cannot add a reference to a .NET Core project to a .NET Framework project.

To share code between .NET Core and .NET Framework apps / libraries, the shared project must target .NET Standard. If you create a .NET Standard 2.0 project, it can be used in .NET Framework 4.6.1+ projects and .NET Core 2.0+ projects.

Comment: This was very useful. After searching for a good hour or so about how to do it, wading through the "reference .net framework from .net core dll" (basically the inverse of what I wanted) and trying to get my .NET Core App 2.0 project to also produce .NET 4.7 compatible bits, this answer made it all click.